# Property of a covariant derivative of a vector field along a curve

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I am studying the covariant derivative of a vector field $X$ along a curve $\gamma$ ( $\nabla_{\dot \gamma}X:=\frac{\nabla X}{dt}$) and I have read the following property:
$$\nabla_{\dot \gamma}X=\Big(\frac{d \xi^k}{dt}+\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{dx^i}{dt}\xi^j\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial_k}$$
In order to prove this above I have thought that if $X=\xi^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ and $\dot \gamma= \frac{dx^i}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, we have that:
since $\nabla X=\Big(\frac{\partial \xi^k}{\partial x^j}+\Gamma_{ji}^k\xi^j\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial_k}$ we obtain:
$$\nabla_{\dot \gamma}X=\nabla_{\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}(\xi^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})=\frac{dx^i}{dt}\Big(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}}(\xi^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})\Big)=\frac{dx^i}{dt}\Big(\xi^j\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})\Big)+\frac{dx^i}{dt}\Big(\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}=\Big(\frac{dx^i}{dt}\xi^j\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}+\color{red}{\frac{dx^i}{dt}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big)=\Big(\frac{dx^i}{dt}\xi^j\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}+\color{red}{\frac{d\xi^j}{dt}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big)=\Big(\frac{dx^i}{dt}\xi^j\Gamma_{ij}^k+{\frac{d\xi^k}{dt}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$
where the last equality is obtained considering the index $j$ in the second term as $k$.

$\textbf{My question:}$ do you think that the passages that I have done are correct? In particular it is valid the equality that involves the red quantities (I am not sure that is mathematically rigorous)?

Comment: Where did the second summand $\dfrac{dx^i}{dt}\big(\xi^j\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\big)$ come from? (I won't ask what it means.)

Comment: No, you have not. You should then have the term $\dfrac{dx^i}{dt}\big(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\xi^j\big)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. Now you have to figure out what that means. (You also have a $-$ in your formula in your comment which needs to be a $+$.)

Comment: Sorry I have written some mistakes in the previous comment the right formula is : $\nabla_{X}(fY)=f\nabla_X Y+X(f)Y$, but this not this passage that is my interest...

Comment: I agree. So I told you the proper term you should have. But since  $X$ is defined only along $\gamma$, it's better to use $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\xi^j$ for this term from the beginning, which gives you $\dfrac{d\xi^j}{dt}$ in their formula.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want to mean! But above all my question regards the passage referred to terms in red...there are some mistakes in the previous ones?

Comment: Yes. You never answered my serious question in the first comment. That term doesn't belong there and also means nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward application of the properties of the covariant derivative. Remember that the Christoffel symbols are defined as a measure of how the covariant derivative acts on the basis vectors:

### $$\nabla_{j}\mathrm{e}_i=\Gamma^k_{ij}\mathrm{e}_k$$

And also that the covariant derivative is linear:

### $$\nabla_\mathrm{u}\mathrm{v}=\nabla_{u^j\mathrm{e}_j}\mathrm{v}=u^j\nabla_{j}\mathrm{v}=u^j\nabla_j(v^i\mathrm{e}_i)$$

Now we use the other important property of the covariant derivative, the product rule

### $$u^j\nabla_j(v^i\mathrm{e}_i)=u^j(\mathrm{e}_i\nabla_j(v^i)+v^i\nabla_j(\mathrm{e}_i))$$

Since covariant differentiation on a scalar is the same as partial differentiation, we get

### $$=u^j(\mathrm{e}_i\partial_jv^i+v^i\Gamma^k_{ij}\mathrm{e}_k)$$
$$=\left(u^j\partial_jv^k+v^iu^j\Gamma^k_{ij}\right)\mathrm{e}_k$$

Replacing $\mathrm{u}$ with $\dot{\gamma}$ with components $\{\dot{x}^i\}$ and replacing $\mathrm{v}$ with $\mathrm{X}$ with components $\{\xi^j\}$, using $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ instead of the more linear algebra type notation $\mathrm{e}_k$ and renaming some indices will give your desired expression.

## **ADDITION:**

It is indeed correct that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi^i}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial \xi^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^j}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
See [exact differential](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactDifferential.html).

Comment: A question: I have not understood if is correct saying from the last passage that $\frac{dx^j}{dt}\partial_j \xi^i=\frac{dx^j}{dt}\frac{\partial \xi^i}{\partial x^j}=\color{red}{\frac{dx^j}{dt}\frac{\partial \xi^i}{\partial x^j}}=\frac{d\xi^i}{dt}$

Comment: @pawel Yes, this is correct. That is a total derivative of $\xi^i$

Comment: @pawel See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct computation (which you can find in any number of texts).
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\dot\gamma}X &= \nabla_{\dot\gamma}\big(\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\big) \\
&= \big(\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\xi^j\big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} + \xi^j\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \\
&= \frac{d\xi^j}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} + \xi^j\nabla_{\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \\
&= \frac{dx^j}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} + \xi^j\frac{dx^i}{dt} \Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.
\end{align*}
Can you finish now?

Note that because a priori $X$ is a vector field only along the curve (this can be fixed, but it's not worth the trouble), $\xi^j$ are functions only of $t$, not of $x^1,\dots,x^n$. So this is why we cannot change $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}$ immediately. Indeed, $d\xi^j/dt$ is typical shorthand for $d(\xi^j\circ\gamma)/dt$.

Comment: In the last passage as first term is not $\frac{d\xi^j}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial j}$?

Comment: I do not understand your question. If your vector field is defined on an open subset of the manifold, not just along the curve, then it will make sense to write the chain rule $\dfrac{d\xi^j}{dt} = \dfrac{\partial\xi^j}{\partial x^i}\dfrac{dx^i}{dt}$. My computation shows you can do this assuming $X$ is defined *just* along $\gamma$.